# Best practice when sharing data/models between tabs of a TabBarController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a `TabBarController` in which I would like to share data between the tabs. Each tab has its own Controller. I have read up on the many ways to achieve this in iOS and Swift. Reading online, I have read up on the disadvantages to the `Singleton` pattern such as global mutability and reduced testability and have decided to not use that pattern. I have decided to go with a `dependency injection` pattern.

I was wondering if the way I am using this pattern in Swift is the correct way or if I am violating principles of iOS development. As a new iOS developer I would like to hear answers on whether I am going the right or wrong way about this.

Here is my `TabBarController` class:

```
class ExampleTabsController: UITabBarController {

var exampleModel: ExampleModel = ExampleModel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadViewControllers()
}

func loadViewControllers() {
    //initialize the storyboards with their respective controllers
    let firstViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "First", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "FirstView") as! FirstController
    let SecondViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Second", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "SecondView") as! SecondController
    
    //create the tab bar items for each view controller
    firstViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .more, tag: 0)
    secondViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .more, tag: 1)
    
    //create a list of all the controllers that will be loaded into the tab bar
    let tabBarList = [firstViewController, secondiewController]
    
    //load the tab bar
    viewControllers = tabBarList
}
```

And here is how my `Controllers` are coded.

```
class FirstController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var list: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let tabBar = tabBarController as! ExampleTabsController
    
    list.text = String(describing:tabBar.exampleModel.exampleList)
}

}
```

Now this all works fine and I am able to display the data in labels on the `Views` of the tabs, but I was wondering if this would be considered poor iOS development practices. Going online, there are many articles with many different ways and this seemed to be a good way without using the `Singleton` pattern with all of its disadvantages. I was wondering if my example is using `dependency injection` properly? Any help is appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let tabBar = tabBarController as! ExampleTabsController
```

But what if your ExampleViewController's tabBarController will be other UITabBarController or nil? Your architecture will stop working.
Your ExampleTabsController and FirstController are coupled very hard.
I can suggest you a little fix:

Add reference to your model inside FirstViewController:

```
var model: ExampleModel?
```

Inject it in your ExampleTabsController's loadViewControllers() function:

```
firstViewController.model = self.exampleModel
```

Now your ExampleTabsController and FirstViewController are not coupled.

Comment: This is great and gives me a better view of dependency injection with Swift! Just a question though, lets say I want this model to be shared between different tabs. Would I assign this model from the TabBarController into all of its tab views and since it is of reference type (it is a class), they will all share the same model and thus be able to modify and share data between tabs?

Comment: Yes, they will.